# Efficient Matrix construction for a weighted Euclidean distance

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I have M points in 2-dimensional Euclidean space, and have stored them in an array X of size M x 2.

I have constructed a cost matrix whereby element ij is the distance d(X[i, :], X[j, :]). The distance function I am using is the standard Euclidean distance weighted by an inverse of the matrix D. i.e d(x,y)= < D^{-1}(x-y) , x-y >. I would like to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this, note I have practically avoided for loops.

```
import numpy as np

Dinv = np.linalg.inv(D)


def cost(X, Dinv):

    Msq = len(X) ** 2
    mesh = []
    for i in range(2):  # separate each coordinate axis
        xmesh = np.meshgrid(X[:, i], X[:, i])  # meshgrid each axis
        xmesh = xmesh[1] - xmesh[0]  # create the difference matrix
        xmesh = xmesh.reshape(Msq)  # reshape into vector
        mesh.append(xmesh)  # save/append into list

    meshv = np.vstack((mesh[0], mesh[1])).T  # recombined coordinate axis

    # apply D^{-1}
    Dx = np.einsum("ij,kj->ki", Dinv, meshv)


    return np.sum(Dx * meshv, axis=1)  # dot the elements
```

Comment: Arrays of size (N, 2) tends to be inefficient compared to the alternative (2,N) . This is because the former is not SIMD friendly, because Numpy is not optimised for small dimension (this is a pain to optimize so we did not tried to do that yet except in few rare cases) but also because of the inefficient memory layout. Indeed, reading `X[:, 0]` cause the whole `X` to be read from the memory while only half the value are needed. `X[:, 1]` re-read the values again so it could be 2x faster (especially if the array do not fit in cache).

Comment: Besides this, can you specify which part is a bottleneck or complete the example so it can be reproducible?

Answer (score 1):

I ll try something like this, mostly optimizing your `meshv` calculation:

```
meshv = (X[:,None]-X).reshape(-1,2)
((meshv @ Dinv.T)*meshv).sum(1)
```